# Wrapping ROS messages using a backward compatible format?

Tags: serialization, ros

ROS message definitions are neither backward nor forward compatible. This is a problem when building largish systems in largish organizations, for all the same reasons that are familiar to those working with RPC-style messaging in distributed systems. In that world the problem has been solved for a long time using backward-compatible message formats (e.g. [protobuffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/), [thrift](https://thrift.apache.org/), [flatbuffers](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/), etc.)

Question: does anyone have any real-life/production-tested experience/code/links to share that use similar schemes with ROS? I have done the obvious things already (sticking a serialized flatbuffer inside a byte array in a ROS message), but want to see if people have already done something better.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a feature that is missing in ROS and ROS2. A workaround could be to wrap a JSON or XML file as a string message inside your ROS messages. Inside the JSON you can have a protocol version string to archive backward compatible messages.